# Celery is constantly starting with supervisor

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

How to run celery in Supervisor?
This is my .conf file:

```
[program:celery_worker]
command=celery -A urlextractor worker -l info
process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr
numprocs=1
directory=/home/omuntean/Django/urlextractor /urlextractor ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
autostart=true ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=unexpected ; when to restart if exited after running
user=root
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stdout_logfile=/var/log/urlextractor/celery_w_out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/urlextractor/celery_w_err.log
```

If I run the celery command normally it works fine without any errors, however, when I type:

> sudo service supervisor start

Then see the status with:

> supervisorctl status

It gives me:

> celery_worker RUNNING    pid 10651, uptime 0:00:02
>
> urlextractor  RUNNING    pid 9761, uptime 0:08:08

And then after I type again it gives me:

> celery_worker STARTING
>
> urlextractor  RUNNING    pid 9761, uptime 0:08:09

Why is this happening and how can I make it work?

Comment: Have you checked the log files?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing written in them.

Comment: Try starting supervisord in the foreground with the -n option, maybe you can see what happens.

Comment: That might happen because of the space in the logfile entries.

Comment: When I run supervisord -n it gives me that celery_worker is exiting and entering running state.

Comment: And when you become root (ugh, why?), cd to the start directory and run `celery -A urlextractor worker -l info` by hand?

Comment: it says "Running a worker with superuser privileges when the
worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!"

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. Its the user. Mine is set to root. Celery does not permit to be activated via root unless it is forced. I only had to change the user.